# Reading .txt file into array Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read a file (stored on the web server) into an array. When I print the array I currently get "undefined". Here is the code im using:

```
var cardRules = new Array;
    $.get('UserFile.txt', function(data){
            var array = data.split('\n');
            console.log(cardRules);
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: var array is local variable for the success callback and cardRules wasn't filled in you code

Answer (score 3):

The 'cardRules' variable never gets populated with the array data. Instead of 
    `var array = data.split('\n');`
just use 
    `cardRules = data.split('\n');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var cardRules = new Array();
    $.get('UserFile.txt', function(data){
            cardRules = data.split('\n');
            console.log(cardRules);
        });
```

Comment: It still is saying "undefined"

Comment: \n - represent new line.Why you split the array by \n ?

Comment: because I want to split the array for each new line in the txt file

Comment: I don't think that an array has new line between each value. Can you show me your array?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm explaining myself clear enough. 

For each new line in my UserFile.txt, I want it to be stored in the index of an array, and then the next index etc.

Comment: Who can help you if you do not show all the code necessary for creating script?

Comment: I get this error
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: see my answer here

Answer (score 0):

Try full url instead of just relative linking

`http://yoursite.com/yourfilelocation/yourfile.txt`

`$.get('http://yoursite.com/yourfilelocation/yourfile.txt', function(data){
            var cardRules = data.split('\n');
            console.log(cardRules);
        });`