# How to convert a file's content into array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have file called "temperatures.txt". It includes the text:

```
22,
21,
23
```

How do I copy the file's content into a JavaScript array?

```
var temperatures = [22, 21, 23];
```

Comment: Read file content, split it's content on `\r\n` and you have JS array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading .txt file into array Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969741/reading-txt-file-into-array-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @Justinas - really? Commas should be part of the array?

Comment: @HappyJoe - are the commas actually a part of the file? And is the file actually split onto new lines as you've shown?

Comment: @HappyJoe - which part of the problem do you have? Do you know how to read the file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Split on comma, then trim? Avoids issues with inconsistent whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

If your text looks like this

```
var txt = "22,21,23";
```

you can convert it to an array like this

```
var array = txt.split(',');
```

or, if theres also a new line do

```
var array = txt.split(',\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text

```
var mytxt = "10,20,30";
```

Convert into array

var array = mytxt .split(',');

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "22,\
           21,\
           23";

// this will remove spaces as well
var result = str.split(/\s*,\s*/);

console.log(result);
```